# Текст после P. S. пишется с большой буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная, оформление-текста, абзац

> Это делается так-то.
>
> P. S. но вообще лучше так не делать

`Но` с большой буквы или с маленькой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку P. S. означает *написанное после*, то — как отдельное приложение к письму, сообщению — оно обязано писаться с прописной (ведь и основной текст письма всегда должен завершаться точкой или иным подобным образом), а также не может быть буквальным продолжением фразы, как в вашем случае.

В то же время трудно также представить, что приложение не является дополнением к сказанному ранее, а смысловым противопоставлением ему, как у вас. Рекомендовать что-то, а потом отвергать это же, наверное, можно, но не через знак P. S.

И наконец (в смысле «в конце концов»), сообщение P. S. пишется абзацем, т. е. с красной строки, где прописная предопределена.

Answer (score 3):

С большой:

**P. S. Но, вообще, лучше так не делать.**

Это сокращение латинского *post scriptum*, после S стоит одна точка, которая обозначает и сокращение слова, и конец предложения, т. к. пунктуационные знаки не удваиваются. То есть P. S. —  это отдельное предложение:
Post scriptum. Но, вообще, лучше так не делать.

*Вообще* в значении "вообще говоря" является вводным и обособляется. На мой взгляд, в Вашем примере как раз этот случай.

Answer (score 2):

Да, текст после P.S. пишется с большой буквы.

На первый взгляд, странно, что такой текст вынесен в post scriptum. Но не видя всего письма, трудно что-то утверждать наверняка.

Фраза "Но вообще лучше так не делать" воспринимается неоднозначно. Если Вы хотите сказать "**Но лучше так не делать вообще**", то советую именно так и построить фразу. А если Вы хотите сказать, что вообще-то говоря, лучше так не делать, то после *вообще* нужно поставить запятую, потому что в данном случае это вводное слово. Запятая между *но* и *вообще* не нужна. Вводное слово обычно не отделяется знаком препинания от присоединительного союза, стоящего в начале предложения.(см. [3. Вводное слово и союз](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2))

**Но вообще, лучше так не делать.**